# Where is this <tr> height coming from?

Tags: html, css

I've got an embedded widget from The Weather Channel and everything is working fine except that they've got a `<tr>` with a 1px height image that is expanding to a height equal to the other rows.

It's shifting the rest of the content down. Because it's just an embed, there is only so much of the styling I can control. But I figured it must be inheriting something from my stylesheet since it had inherited some line-height that I had to correct.

If you visit http://www.scwd.com and scroll to the bottom you'll see the weather widget. The row with the grey td below @weather.com is the issue. It should only be 1px in height. I've used multiple debuggers to see if I could find the inherit and I cannot. Any help would be great.

-- UPDATE --

Not the most elegant solution considering variable within the widget and out of my control may change in the future. But as David suggested, I solved it with the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = $("img[src$='blank.gif']");
$(x).closest('tr').css('display', 'none');
</script>
```

Comment: I've just edited your post so the `<tr>` shows up -- if you're putting HTML code inline with your questions/answers here, wrap it with backticks to escape it.

Comment: I changed the background color of the td element that contains the image to transparent and it seemed to look better.  Right now it's set to #66666.  Unfortunately it looks like that is an inline style and if you don't have control over the individual elements of the widget that might not help you.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes SRM, that's an inline style and why I think if I can just figure out how to get that one row to shrink back to 1px I'll be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best I can find is:

```
Inherited from div#wx_module_6107.wow_container
.wow_container {
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

Are you hosting this or pulling the HTML from a foreign source?  I suspect you can't control the HTML that's being rendered or the CSS that it's using?

I'm no CSS expert, so thus far nothing I've tried in FireBug have made a difference without affecting the rest of the table elements in the widget.

Unless someone can give a CSS solution, maybe some JavaScript can get the job done?  You should be able to, on document ready, find that `img` element (maybe by its `src`?) and from there (using something like .closest() in jQuery) find its parent `td` and parent `tr` and with those element references explicitly set their styles.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, I'll work on it and reply if I solve it.

Comment: @samseaborn: Well, "good" is a relative term.  I'm not 100% happy with a workaround like this from a code elegance perspective, but if it gets the job done then it's not too bad.  My biggest concern is how reliable it's going to be to find that `img`, or if that widget's markup is going to change over time.

Comment: That along isn't going to solve it (it will still appears to be ~5px in height). But trying to make up a CSS that will. ;-)

Comment: agreed, but client insists on this TWC widget, so I have to find a way that's "not too bad", eh? :)

Answer (score 1):

The image is in a td which has a line height of 14 according to your css:

```
.wow_container { line-height: 14px; }
```

I would give it a line-height of 1px and set the background-color to transparent. That makes things look nice for me. Is this widget coming from a wordpress plugin? If so which plugin? You may be able to edit the plugin code yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the background-color of one specific <td> because the whole thing is inserted by the script. Also, if I set the line-height to 1px it shoves the entire list together for me? Are you seeing different results?

Comment: Is this widget from a wordpress plugin? You can probably fix the plugin code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs because the `font-size` of the `body`. My suggestion is to add `font:1px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif` for the `td` that is the grey row.